# How to redirect to another screen after adding asyncstorage data

Tags: react-native, button, react-navigation, hybrid-mobile-app, asyncstorage

I am new to react native, trying to redirect and add data on Same button press event. I have tried using .then after await operation, but not working
Either it is adding data or it's redirecting- don't know how to combine both ?

```javascript
   <Button title="Add now !" 
            onPress={ ()=> addtoStorage(initname, initclas, initsubject) }

 addtoStorage = async(par1, par2, par3) =>{
       
        try{
            
            let makeObject = {name:par1, class:par2, subject:par3, 
                              id: Increase.key.toString()};
             console.log(makeObject);
             await AsyncStorage
               .setItem( makeObject.id , JSON.stringify(makeObject) )
             .then(Increase())
             .then(moveAround.navigate(first)); //not working here
        } catch(e){

        }
       console.log('done');
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it finally, didn't need .then statements

I just did setItem (semicolon) and then moved to first or desired screen.

```js
   await AsyncStorage.setItem(makeObject.id , JSON.stringify(makeObject));
    moveAround.navigate('first');
```